# automatically register cleanup function when leaving function scope

Tags: python, inspect

I have a function that take a collection of objects as an argument. In the event that I access a member of the collection, I want to call a cleanup function of that member **at the end of that that function call** (basically, send it back to redis when the function is finished mutating the object)

so for example:

```
class foo():
  value = 0
  clean = True

  def modify(self):
    self.value +=1
    self.clean = False

  def cleanup(self):
    if not self.clean:
      # do cleanup stuff (i.e. send dirtied data back to database)
      print("foo cleanup " + str(self.value))
      self.clean = True


def calling_function(collection):
  try:
    collection[1].modify()
  #... do other stuff
  finally:
    for f in collection:
      f.cleanup()


col = [foo(), foo()]

calling_function(col)
```

I'd like to accomplish this functionality without the try/finally block. The idea is that the function using the collection should be agnostic to needing to clean it up, it should just be able to access it and have the data automatically persisted when it falls out of scope (edit: it's not falling out of scope, because the calling scope still has a reference to it)

The only idea I had was to somehow inject an object into the current (function) scope, who's **del** would do what I needed. But that seems messy and I don't even know if it's possible.

Comment: look into `__exit__()`

Comment: decorator? https://www.thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/